# Plot two columns from data frame with different number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I want to plot two columns from a data frame, which is composed of additional columns of different lengths.  The problem is I'm either getting errors of "Error: (converted from warning) Removed 9256 rows containing missing values (position_stack)." or "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion".  Is the only solution to divide the data frame into each data set?
The code is simply:

```
df <- data.frame(dat)
plot(df$orders,df$received)
```

A sample of my data is:

```
datamre <- structure(list(orders = c("0%", "0-5%", "5-10%", "10-15%", "15-20%", 
"20-25%", "25-30%", "30-35%", "35-40%", "40-45%", "45-50%", "50-55%", 
"55-60%", "60-65%", "65-70%", "70-75%", "75-80%", "80-85%", "85-90%", 
"90-95%", "95-100%", ">100%", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), 
    received = c(9275472.19, 2365024.89, 217461.52, 188724.96, 
    885881.12, 390383.32, 405775.84, 55468.47, 29916.11, 372719.22, 
    746920.55, 34302.78, 8307, 3186.66, 6051.51, 67015.73, 42879.31, 
    0, 9011.65, 3346.8, 4644960.79, 6022733.55, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), x = 0:29, cdf = c(0, 0.04545455, 0.04545455, 
    0.04545455, 0.04545455, 0.13636364, 0.13636364, 0.13636364, 
    0.18181818, 0.18181818, 0.22727273, 0.27272727, 0.27272727, 
    0.27272727, 0.27272727, 0.27272727, 0.27272727, 0.27272727, 
    0.27272727, 0.27272727, 0.27272727, 0.27272727, 0.27272727, 
    0.27272727, 0.27272727, 0.27272727, 0.27272727, 0.27272727, 
    0.27272727, 0.27272727), perc = 1:30, cumcosts = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 3.18666, 3.18666, 3.18666, 3.18666, 3.18666, 6.53346, 
    6.53346, 6.53346, 6.53346, 6.53346, 12.58497, 12.58497, 12.58497, 
    12.58497, 12.58497, 20.89197, 20.89197, 20.89197, 20.89197, 
    29.90362, 29.90362, 29.90362, 29.90362, 29.90362, 59.81973, 
    59.81973)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What exactly do you want this plot to look like? Do you want a barplot? Try `barplot(datamre$received,names.arg = datamre$orders)`..

Comment: Yes, I wanted a barplot, but couldn't get past the errors.  Tried your solution, but it only plotted the 0% bar.